# How can I run an HTML5 validator against an entire website?

Tags: html, validation, batch-file

I've been using HTML5 in websites for about a year now, but the W3C doesn't offer an option to check if an entire domain is valid.  There are tools out there to do this with HTML4, but they aren't helpful in HTML5.

Is there an online service or browser extension that can solve this problem?  I've looked but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see the one I wrote? It uses an instance of the Validator.nu engine on our server and it's called [HTML Validator Pro](http://html.validator.pro/). It goes up to 50 pages for free, but I don't know the size of your domain, so I don't know if this will meet your requirements, but I hope so! Please let me know if it works for you and any feedback you have for me.

Thank You

Comment: It's my pleasure and you're absolutely welcome!

Comment: @ScottGrodberg Awesome work! Great tool.

Answer (score 1):

Looking around online, I found a service here: http://html5.validator.nu that provides HTML 5 verification for the entire domain. Have you also seen Total Validator? http://www.totalvalidator.com It also seems to do what you are looking to accomplish.

Comment: I found validator.nu when searching too but as far as I can tell it only checks one page.  Total Validator I saw earlier as well but it's a paid tool.  Not a deal-breaker but I was hoping for a free tool.  Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: For Total Validator, the basic tools are free to use. They sell a Pro tool though.

Comment: I'll give it a try, maybe it'll accomplish what I'm trying to do.  Thanks.  (I'd upvote you but I'm told I don't have enough reputation - sorry!)

Comment: I installed it to take a look, TotalValidator requires an upgrade to pro for full-site checking.